# I don't know why this 'this' method doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, this

```
const list = {
    name: 'Harry Potter',
    birthYear: 1995,

    calcAge: function () {
        this.age = 2002 - this.birthYear;
        return this.age;
    }
};

console.log(list.age);
```

Comment: Please give more details. What error do you get?

Comment: When I add 'list.age' to the console it tells me it's undefined. Shouldn't this 'this' method add a variable to 'list' because of the function?

Answer (score 1):

You are storing a function, not calling it that's why it should print you `undefined`. To fix it you should call it with `list.calcAge()`.

Your code works and `this.age = 2002 - this.birthYear` creates the property you want, you just need to call it before using it.

```
const list = {
    name: 'Harry Potter',
    birthYear: 1995,

    calcAge: function () {
        this.age = 2002 - this.birthYear;
        return this.age;
    }
};
list.calcAge()
console.log(list.age);
```

Answer (score 1):

Call your function. `list.calcAge()` You can print it like this `console.log(list.calcAge())` You were close though!!

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the advice, but I wanted to store the value in 'age', so I used the 'this' method. But anyway I really appreciate the time you gave me in response, thanks

Comment: How about add a variable `age: ""` then say `"return age = (2002 - this.birthYear)`.  Then `console.log(age)` My syntax could be off a little but this would make sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const list = {
    name: 'Harry Potter',
    birthYear: 1995,

    calcAge() {
        this.age = 2002 - this.birthYear;
        return this.age;
    },
};

console.log(list.calcAge());
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this. It will work.

```js
const list = {
    name: 'Harry Potter',
    birthYear: 1995,

    calcAge: function () {
        this.age = 2002 - this.birthYear;
        return this.age;
    },
};

console.log(list.calcAge());
```

Try calling list.calcAge() in your console

Answer (score -2):

the `calcAge` is function property so you must be treated as a function `list.calcAge()`

[image]

```js
const list = {
name: 'Harry Potter',
birthYear: 1995,
calcAge: function () {
  this.age = 2002 - this.birthYear;
  return this.age;
    }
};
document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = list.name;
document.getElementById("birthYear").innerHTML = list.birthYear;
document.getElementById("age").innerHTML = list.calcAge();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <p id="name"></p>
        <p id="birthYear"></p>
        <p id="age"></p>
    </body>
</html>
```